# How to simplify $(3a-b^2-a)^3$ by using special product?

Tags: polynomials

When I simplify $(3a-b^2-a)^3$, I used $(u±v)^3=u^3±3u^2v+3uv^2±v^3$

but I'm confused with $(b^2-a)$

Comment: You should slow down and absorb the answers on your previous question before continuing to post questions of the same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your cited identity is incorrect; the exponent on the $v$ was wrong in the last term. The correct version is
$$(u\pm v)^3=u^3\pm 3u^2v + 3uv^2\pm v^3.$$
Also, note that
$$3a-b^2-a=2a-b^2$$
so that 
$$(3a-b^2-a)^3=(2a-b^2)^3,$$
and you can then let $u=2a$ and $v=-b^2$, making the problem somewhat more straightforward.

Comment: I guest I need a tutor Thanks sir